# plot() - Numbering on axes disappeared

Tags: r, plot

When I try to plot something, there are no numbers on my axes.

**Example**

`plot(1:10)`
gives

[image: plot without numbers]

**Recent changes**

The only thing I can remember that I have changed recently is that I created a file ~/.Rprofile that contained only the line
`options("width" = 170)`
I am not 100% sure this is the reason the axes lost their numbering.

**What I've tried without success**

- deleting the newly created ~/.Rprofile
- adding margins with `par(mar = c(5,5,3,1))` as suggested in [R: plot has no numbers on axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918211/r-plot-has-no-numbers-on-axis)
- Adding axes by hand with `axis()` as suggested here: [Controlling number formatting at axis of R plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415097/controlling-number-formatting-at-axis-of-r-plots)

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

**sessionInfo()**

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Manjaro Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8        LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8     
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8    
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
```

Comment: If you run `example(plot)`, are those plots also missing their axes?  If so, adding `sessionInfo()` to your question might give someone a clue.

Comment: ah sorry, forogt the sessionInfo(). Yes, example(plot) also don't show numbers on the axes. The axes and ticks are there, however

Comment: I'd guess it's a font problem, but I don't know your OS at all.

Comment: the system is an arch derivative and the desktop is xfce. It used to run without a problem. Now this appears no matter whether I run R from the command line or use RStudio.