# How can I clean up my plot(x,y) line graph labels from overplotting?

Tags: r, plot

I am working with the `babynames` package and am trying to plot the number of births per year within the `babynames::applications` data frame.

Currently I have made it close to the finish line with

`library(babynames) plot(births[1:109,],births[1,], type="l",main="Birthcount Over The Century",xlab="year",)`
But the result is icky and I don't quite understand what is happening within the index brackets.

[image: Resulting Plot with messy Y axis/data labels]

How can I clean this up? I tried changing to `plot(births[1:109,],births[1:109,]` but that makes it overplotted even more with a messier label.

What is happening within the square brackets here exactly?

Comment: When you subset `births` with the square brackets `births[1:109,]`  you still have a `data.frame` with two columns. Therefore it doesn't make sense to provide an additional input to the `plot()` function (e.g. `births[1,]`). In your first plot you see `1909` as an additional label on the y axis because you've added too much data to the function.

Comment: What were you hoping to accomplish by adding the data twice?

Comment: Thank you Dan. I figured I needed to plot x and Y but if the plotted data frame is two columns I now see that's not necessary.

Comment: Actually it's probably more typical to provide `x` and `y` as separate inputs to `plot()` as atomic vectors each. So here that would look like `plot(births$year[1:109], births$births[1:109])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the axis labels with the `axis()` function in `base` `R` graphics which might help you de-crowd the Y axis. Inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36128830/13210554) answer.

```r
library(babynames)
plot(births[1:109, ],  type = "l", main = "Birthcount Over The Century", yaxt="n")
axis(2, at = axTicks(2), labels = paste(formatC(axTicks(2)/1000, format = 'd'), 'k', sep = ''))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Or if you're open to non-base packages... you can get more control with {ggplot2}. Here I'm using `scales::comma` to control formatting of the y axis labels and `ggthemes::theme_base()` to get it to look like the `base` plot if that's what you're after. {scales} has many nice functions to control this formatting to suit your desires.

```r
library(babynames)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)

births %>% 
  filter(year < 2018) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, births)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  labs(title = "Birthcount Over The Century") +
  ggthemes::theme_base() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>